# Notification between Java EE components

Tags: java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee

I have a design problem .

My application has multiple Java EE components ,In simple terms one acts as a service provider(Non UI) and others are consumers(UI webapp) .

The consumer gets the configuration data from the service provider(this basically reads the data from DB) during the start up and stores it in the Cache.

The cache gets refreshed after periodic time to reflect any changes done at the database.

*The Problem*

Apart from the cache refresh, I also want to notify the consumers when someone changes the DB that configuration has been changed please reload it.

What notification mechanisms can I use to achieve this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406984/what-are-the-alternatives-of-jms

Comment: BTW, I don't understand your question. The cache is in the consumer? You have a mechanism to refresh the cache, so the consumer knows when the configuration changed, no? Otherwise, use a timestamp. You check the timestamp periodically, and if the timestamp in cache and the timestamp in db differ, you reload the configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with JMS topics/queues. The producer sending a "REFRESH_CACHE" message on a topic and all consumers listening to this

Comment: Queues wouldn't really work since they're point-to-point (PTP).  Assuming there is more than one consumer you'd want to use a topic (pub/sub)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a topic for it. When the database changes you can send a message to the topic and all clients listen to it, can show a message.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) design pattern. You can store consumers in a list and notify them when something interesting happens.

Answer (score 0):

You may need [OBSERVER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern.
It notifies the consumers (your UI apps) using Callback. You can use JMS for notifications.