# Is it possible give an EJB service call a callback

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

Is it possible to make an EJB service which accepts callbacks and call it on the
client which invokes the service? The use case is: Uploading a large byte array
to the service which will parse it and transform the result into Objects and
persist them. I want to notify the client which of these steps are done.

```
@Local
public interface MyService {
    Status upload(byte[] content, Callable<Void> onReceived, Calable<Void> onPersisting);
}

@Stateless(name = "MyService")
public class MyServiceImpl extends MyService {
    Status upload(byte[] content, Callable<Void> onReceived, Calable<Void> onPersisting) {
        // Invoke this because all date is transfered to server.
        onReceived.call();
        // Do the parsing stuff ...
        onPersisting.call();
        // Do the persisting stuff ...
        return new Status(...); // Done or failed or such.
    }
}
```

On the client I pass in the callables:

```
Context ctx = ...
MyService service = ctx.get(...);

ctx.upload(bytes, new Callable<void() {
    @Override
    public Void call() {
        // Do something
        return null;
    }
}, new Callable<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() {
        // Do something
        return null;
    }
});
```

Is something like that possible in EJB?

I'm new to the JEE world: I know that the client get some stubs of the EJB
interface and the calls are transfered by "background magic" to the servers
real EJB implementation.

Comment: this may help you , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407159/notification-between-java-ee-components

Comment: Is MyService a local or remote business interface?  If it's a remote business interface, then no, you can't do this.  If it's a local business interface, then yes, this should work fine.

Comment: I have to read about the difference first to answer that...

Comment: As far as I understand the code base: All business service interfaces are @Local, but they are called from a remote client via an application client container. Which is a third party module.

Comment: Do you have still a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1: Using a local business interface (or no-interface view)**

Yes it's possible as long as your service is only accessed by an local business interface. Why? A local business interface can be only accessed by local client.

> A local client has these characteristics [[LocalClients]](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipmz/index.html).
>
> - It must run in the same application as the enterprise bean it accesses.
> - It can be a web component or another enterprise bean.
> - To the local client, the location of the enterprise bean it accesses is not transparent.

To summarize the important characteristics. It run in the same application respectively in the same JVM, it's a web or EJB component and that the location of the accessed bean is not transparent for the local client. Please take a look at [LocalClients](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipmz/index.html) for more details.

Below a simple *Hello World* example. My example uses a no-interface view this is equivalent to a local business interface.

Edit: Example expanded by JNDI lookup.

```
/** Service class */

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class Service {

    public void upload(final Callback callback) {
        callback.call();
    }

}

/** Callback class */

public class Callback {

    public void call() {
        System.out.println(this + " called.");
    }

}

/** Trigger class */

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class Trigger {

    @EJB
    Service service;

    @Schedule(second = "*/5", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void triggerService() {
        System.out.println("Trigger Service call");
        service.upload(new Callback());
        //or by JNDI lookup and method overriding
        try {
           Service serviceByLookup = (Service) InitialContext.doLookup("java:module/Service");
           serviceByLookup.upload(new Callback() {
               @Override
               public void call() {
                   System.out.println("Overriden: " + super.toString());
               }
           });

       } catch (final NamingException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

It's also possible to implement the `Callback` class as `StatelessBean` and inject it in the `Service` class.

```
/** Service class */
@Stateless
public class Service {

    @EJB
    Callback callback;

    public void upload() {
        callback.call();
    }

}
```

---

**Case 2: Using a remote business interface**

If you are using a remote interface it's not possible to pass a callback object to your EJB. To get status information back to your client you have to use JMS.

Below a short kick-off example.

```
@Remote
public interface IService {

    void upload();

}

@Stateless
public class Service implements IService {

    @EJB
    private AsyncUploadStateSender uploadStateSender;

    @Override
    public void upload() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 10) {
            uploadStateSender.sendState(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


@Stateless
public class AsyncUploadStateSender {

    @Resource(lookup = "jms/myQueue")
    private Queue queue;

    @Inject
    private JMSContext jmsContext;

    @Asynchronous
    public void sendState(final int state) {
        final JMSProducer producer = jmsContext.createProducer();
        final TextMessage msg = jmsContext.createTextMessage("STATE CHANGED " + state + "%");
        producer.send(queue, msg);
    }
}

public class Client {

    public static void main(final String args[]) throws NamingException, InterruptedException, JMSException {

        final InitialContext ctx = ... // create the InitialContext;
        final IService service = (IService) ctx.lookup("<JNDI NAME OF IService>");
        final ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/__defaultConnectionFactory");
        final Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("jms/myQueue");
        // set consumer
        final Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
        final MessageConsumer consumer = connection.createSession().createConsumer(queue);
        consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(final Message msg) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(((TextMessage) msg).getText());
                } catch (final JMSException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        connection.start();
        // start upload
        service.upload();
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
    }
}
```

Note: you have to create the queue `jms/myQueue` and the connection factory `jms/__defaultConnectionFactory` in your application server to make the example work.

Comment: That something like this is possible I know. I want to give the callback as an argument to the service method.

Comment: @Weltraumschaf, when the services have local business interfaces it should work like shown in my first example.

Comment: Do I understand right, that this is not possible if the service is called via Application Client Container?

Comment: @Weltraumschaf, Yes that's true but you can not call a local business interface through a Application Client Container either.

Comment: Hm, that's what I wanted to do. How does one solve the problem that a long running EJB service updates the client about progress? Something like I can do with websockets in a HTTP environment: There I can hold the connection to the client open and send data continuously back to the client.

Comment: @Weltraumschaf, using JMS would be a good option. A great example could you find here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnchx.html

Comment: I Wangen to avoid the additional complexity of JMS. But thanks so far for your help.